# .net standard Fsharp.Core 4.7.0.0 = 4.5.2?

Tags: .net-core, f#, plotly

I'm trying to use Xplot.Plotly in an f# project using
Visual Studio for Mac.   When I debug I obtain

```
"Could not load file or assembly 
'FSharp.Core, Version=4.7.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

If If I do dotnet run I obtain:

```
Unhandled exception. 
   Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed.
```

the project file references are as follows

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MathNet.Numerics.FSharp" Version="4.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="XPlot.Plotly" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the project view screen shot as follows:
[image: dependencies Fsharp.Core]

I'm not clear why VS shows 4.5.2 instead of 4.7.0.0?

I've also tried moving explicityly the Fsharp.core.dll version 4.7.0.0 to the bin directory.  From the console the result is the same.  If I run via Visual studio Fsharp.core.dll version 4.7.0.0 gets overwritten with 4.5.2.0 and fails in the same way as above.

Update: Workaround is simply do Clean from Visual Studio. and then run dotnet build from the console.   Then you can debug from Visual Studio if needed.

Comment: Try setting `COREHOST_TRACE=1` to get the assembly binding log.

Comment: @Asti  thanks. I did, however it didn't change anything as using the command line throws an unhandled exception whereas visual studio is the one complaining about the file not found dependency when debugging.

Comment: @Asti actually I did get a trace file from after the setting the env variable.   everything looks fine. e.g. all "Probed deps json and matched"

Comment: Trace prints on `stderr`, not `stdout`, so you'd have to capture it. 4.7 is maybe being referenced by the project itself (not nuget). Can you open the fsproj in a text editor and check?

Comment: @asti indeed the project file points to FSharp.Core 4.7.1. not sure why VS shows it as 4.5.2.  However when I look at the trace only 4.5.2 is used there's no 4.7. in the trace whatsoever.

Comment: @KoenigLear It looks like it is time to start counting the [issues](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues/883#issuecomment-602721464) =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, VS for Mac requires Mono, which is locked to F# 4.5 and has numerous other troubles loading .NET Standard 2.0 components. Eventually, VS for Mac will be updated and it will support loading higher versions of the F# compiler and FSharp.Core.